# Decryption Returns x00 Stream

Tags: c#, encryption, stream, null

I got a problem with decrypting using CryptoStream to MemoryStream. When I decrypt a data that converted from a string to byte[] it decrypts normally, but when I pass an image data to the decryptor it returns x00 filled stream with the same length as the image data. Btw, no exception thrown.

```
private SymmetricAlgorithm crypto;

...

public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] Stream)
    {
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = crypto.CreateEncryptor();
        // Create the streams used for encryption. 
        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                int written = 0;
                int length = Stream.Length;
                int blockSize = crypto.BlockSize / 8;
                while (written < length)
                {
                    int toWrite = Math.Min(blockSize, length - written);
                    if ((length - written) > blockSize)
                    {
                        csEncrypt.Write(Stream, written, blockSize);
                        written += blockSize;
                        csEncrypt.Flush();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        csEncrypt.Write(Stream, written, toWrite);
                        written += toWrite;
                        csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
                    }
                }
                resBytes = msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }
        return resBytes;
    }

...

public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] Stream)
    {
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = crypto.CreateDecryptor();
        MemoryStream decrypted = new MemoryStream();

        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(Stream))
        {
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
            csDecrypt.CopyTo(decrypted, crypto.BlockSize);
            resBytes = decrypted.ToArray();                    
            decrypted.Dispose();

            resBytes = decrypted.ToArray();
            return resBytes;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you call `Flush` and `FlushFinalBlock`? If you move your `resBytes = msEncrypt.ToArray();` to ouside `CryptoStream`'s `using` block you don't need to call any flushes at all. Also your `int blockSize = crypto.BlockSize / 8;` seems kind of pointless, you don't need to call `Write` in multiples of `BlockSize` the underlying classes handle the breaking the blocks apart for you. There is no reason not to write the entire array at once.

Comment: Why would you decrypt an image? Passing in malformed data would result in malformed data out. You can't just decrypt random blocks of data.

Comment: Scott, thanks for the tricks, it works and reduces my code line a lot. But I'm asking about the decryption, it doesn't work for byte[] from encrypted file.

Travis I encrypted an image file and decrypt it. (Not decrypting a normal image file) Which returns zero bytes inside the output stream.